# About DateTime Error

Tags: c#-4.0, datetime

I am retrieving date and passing to the function :

```
Bind(GetDate(Convert.ToString(Session["TransDate"])),
GetDate((Convert.ToDateTime(Session["TransDate"]).AddDays(1)).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")));
```

The get date function is described below :

```
private String GetDate(String strDate)
{
        String strDate1 = String.Empty;
        if (strDate != "")
        {
            String[] arrDate = strDate.Split('/');
            if (arrDate.Length == 1)
            {
                arrDate = strDate.Split('-');
            }
            strDate1 = arrDate[1] + "/" + arrDate[0] + "/" + arrDate[2];
        }
        return strDate1;
}
```

it gives me error as :

```
 "string was not recognized as a valid date time".
```

Comment: Why are you doing all of these string conversions at all? Why is `Session["TransDate"]` not just a `DateTime` which you can *leave* as a `DateTime`? If you really want to keep with this approach, I suggest you break your very complicated statement into pieces, so it's easier to debug - in particular, you want to look at what you're passing into `Convert.ToDateTime.`

Comment: Why you are writing a code to split things .. i have posted my answer try with that

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM dd yy"");
```

or

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; 
string s = dt.ToString("MM dd yy"");

s= "10 28 13";
```